# Coloring sides of truncated triangular dihedral (bipyramid) into 3 colours

Tags: coloring, dihedral-groups

I need to find out  the amount of ways to colour truncated triangular dihedron into 3 colours. So, the task will be easier if I had simple triangular dihedron.

First of all, do I understand right that truncated dihedron looks like :

> [image]

The only things I know, that I must use Burnsside's lemma, calculate symmetries (rotations).

By the way, if you know some beginners algebra books with decent amount of examples in practice and more-or-less easy to understand for not English-speaker, thank you.

Comment: As far as I remember, "dihedron" means "a body having two faces". The least possible number of faces of a body in $3D$ is however 4 (tetrahedron)... A dihedron would be just a two-sided plane figure.

Comment: My mistake, I meant bipyramid, sorry

Comment: The next issue is meaning of "truncated". I would assume it means it is truncated by planes parallel to the base, so that the body has 8 faces (two equilateral triangles and 6 isosceles trapezoids).

Comment: @user I had this question too. In this case truncated means the dihedral consist of two truncated triangular piramids, alternatively saying, instead of lower and upper vericles there are triangles. So, the number of size is 6+2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first of all  that we obtain a cube when  placing vertices at the
centers of  the hexagonal faces  and connecting those where  the faces
share  an  edge. So  we  could  solve  this  problem by  asking  about
colorings of the vertices and the faces of the cube. We will work with
the  given  solid   however.  (The  cube  was  solved   at  this  [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2828924/)).

We evidently require the cycle index.  There is the identity and three
types of rotations.  With $a_q$ for hexagonal faces and  $b_p$ for the
pyramids at the corners we get from the identity:

$$a_1^8 b_1^6.$$

The rotations about an axis passing through opposite pyramidal corners
contribute

$$3 \times (2 a_4^2 b_1^2 b_4 + a_2^4 b_1^2 b_2^2).$$

The flips about an axis passing through the centers of two opposite edges
($180$ degree rotation) contribute

$$6 \times a_2^4 b_2^3.$$

Finally, the rotations by $60$ degrees and $120$ degrees about an axis
passing through the centers of opposite hexagonal faces yields

$$4 \times 2 a_1^2 a_3^2 b_3^2.$$

We thus have for the cycle index

$$Z(T) = \frac{1}{24}
(a_1^8 b_1^6 + 6 a_4^2 b_1^2 b_4 + 3 a_2^4 b_1^2 b_2^2
+ 6 a_2^4 b_2^3 + 8 a_1^2 a_3^2 b_3^2).$$

We then get  by Burnside for colorings with at  most $N$ colors shared
between hexagonal faces and pyramidal corners the closed form:

$$\frac{1}{24}(N^{14} + 6 N^5 + 3 N^8 + 6 N^7 + 8 N^6).$$

This gives the sequence

$$1, 776, 200961, 11198720, 254387500, 3265470936, 28260264606,
\\ 183254654976, 953206454115, 4166682025000, \ldots$$

in particular for $N=3$ we obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
200961.}$$

The formula when working with exactly $N$ colors as opposed to at most
$N$ colors is (colors are shared between pyramids and hexagons):

$$\frac{N!}{24}\left({14\brace N}
+ 6 {5\brace N} + 3 {8\brace N}
+ 6 {7\brace N} + 8 {6\brace N}\right).$$

This gives the finite sequence

$$1, 774, 198636, 10399528, 200395755, 1903119150, 10359167700,
\\ 35132702640, 77643165600, 113816102400, 109880971200,
\\ 67199932800, 23610787200, 3632428800, 0, 0, \ldots $$

because there  are only fourteen  slots available. Note that  the last
one is $$14!/24 = 3632428800.$$

**Remark.** This cycle index also  solves the problem where colors are
not shared between hexagons and pyramids. We find:

$$\frac{1}{24}
(N^8 M^6 + 6 N^2 M^3 + 3 N^4 M^4
+ 6 N^4 M^3 + 8 N^4 M^2).$$

Comment: I fucking love u man, best of luck to you,  but as I see u did it for the figire of picture I provided in question . The figure I must solve is simple dihedral, but it consist of 2 truncated piramids, so we have 8 faces to colour ( imagine like we cut upper and lower part a bit). Am I right, that I need just do it for a18 without b? Sorry for bad english

Comment: There are a number of examples at [MSE Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#13335). I suggest you consult these and learn the technique in order to be able to solve this type of problem yourself.

Comment: Yep, I will have work for today's evening probably, thank you again mate

Comment: for this dihedral [picture](https://imggmi.com/full/2019/1/12/76c121dfe6ce39bdf7f33b6c19be12a6-full.jpg.html)  I found:
1) 2 rotations by 120 degrees, which change only the vericles in the middle triangle + identity e( nothing changes)
2) 3 rotations by 180 degrees passing through medians of triangles ( so 2 triangles vericles exchange and also small triangles exchange)
is it all? or I missed something? Because I found [your solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852921/coloring-a-triangular-bipyramid) where almost same figure and there is more cycles...

Comment: As I am trying to understand I need to find group of rotations, for example, lets upper 1 triangle be 1, lower be 2, 3 faces of upper part 2,3,4 and lower part 5,6,7, so I can write rotations as permulations , for example for identity (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8), for rotations of triangles vericles (1)(234)(567)(8) and so on, and then the length of cycles will be degrees for N in burnside formula? Sorry for molestaion.

Comment: did I miss something in rotations, because I feel really hard to configure in my head all the rotations, flips and reflections correctly.

Comment: I suggest you collect these observations into a new post where everyone can see them, including providing a definite image of the solid you are working with. Replies are likely when you show this much effort. You also need to decide whether you want to work with rotations only or include reflections. The example above is restricted to rotations. Hint: factoring these rotations into cycles does not require table notation or lables on the faces. Try to learn how to factor them by inspection, rotating the solid in your mind and observing the cycles that form.

Comment: I had a thought to make a new question, but think I will annoy people asking 2nd question about task which already was explained, since it seems like I am just too stupid for algebra overall

Comment: You could explain that you are looking for a different solid from what I answered.

Comment: ok I will do this

Comment: by the way, what do indexes above and below a and b mean?

Comment: The term $a_2^3$ represents three two-cycles. The terrm $a_5^4$ represents four five-cycles, etc. A two-cycle has two elements, a five cycle, five.